# could not match simplexml object and variable?

Tags: php, variables, simplexml

I have a php file in which a xml file is loaded through simplexml and is searched for corresponding id, everything works fine but when matching the id with the given one, it doesnt work, If I echo both of them, they are displayed but if I use if statement to match they wont match

here is my php code

```
  <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$cat_xml= simplexml_load_file('http://artstack.com/sites/77/site_categories.xml'); 
$product_xml= simplexml_load_file('http://artstack.com/sites/77/site_products.xml'); 



function getcatid($product_name,$product_xml){
    foreach($product_xml as $product){
        if($product){
            if($product_name==$product->url){
                return $product->cat_id;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getcat($cat_id,$cat_xml){
    foreach($cat_xml as $cat){
        if($cat){
            if($cat_id==$cat->id){
                echo $cat['name'];
            }
            else{
                if(isset($cat->category)){
                    //sub cat
                    foreach($cat->category as $subcat){
                        if($subcat){
                            echo $cat_id." > ".$subcat->id."<br>";
                            if($cat_id==$subcat->id){
                                echo $cat_id." > ".$subcat->id."<br>";
                                exit;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }   
}

getcat(getcatid($_GET['pro'],$product_xml),$cat_xml);
?>
```

Output is

```
75 > 73
75 > 74
75 > 75
```

but it must be

```
75 > 73
75 > 74
75 > 75
75 > 75
```

Comment: try use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` to see variable dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I used type casting

```
if(intval($cat_id)==intval($subcat->id)){
```

THANKS

Comment: Indeed, simplexml returns a simplexmlobject that, when echo'd appears fine, but is not a string and therefore fails string comparisons (or int comparisons). webbandit's tip would have gotten you the same information.